# how to read emails from an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to implement this: an iPhone app will download user's emails(based on user settings) from the email server (e.g. gmail.com) through IMAP protocol. Would like to download email text as well as attachment. Is this possible? Are there open-source or sample code for this work already? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the open source **reMail-iphone** product http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/